# 64-bit applications crash whenever Open or Save dialogue comes up

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, crash, windows-10-upgrade

I know it has already been asked here, but none of the previous answers have worked, so I'll ask again.

After I upgraded my Windows 7 64-bit to Windows 10 64-bit, all my 64-bit applications have had this strange problem where it crashes if I need to open a save or load dialogue. 32-bit applications work fine.

I have tried everything I've managed to google my way to with no success.
I don't have any network drives or folders. I don't have Microsoft Office. I don't have BINS, OldNewExplorer or any other MS-fix applications. The problem persists even if I run the app as Admin.

I've tried every "quick fix" application Microsoft has thrown out there, but nothing seems to work. I really don't want to reinstall Windows as I have a broken laptop screen and using an external one and I don't think this laptop can handle that during the installation process, so I'm desperate for a solution that works. I don't even know what end to start right now.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: It's a single question about a very specific problem. I thought I had already given very much details, what other details do you need?

The problem is that every 64-bit application crashes when I get to a save or open dialogue box.

I've also listed every single answer to all other threads here that I could find, along with some others from outside this site that I have excluded as the source of my problem.

The one single answer I want is what the problem may be, so I can fix it.

Comment: You didn't list any of the "fixes" you tried and their results...

Comment: @ChristianKarlsson - Please read the entire comment before you focus on a single segment of the comment.  The comment also indicates you should provide enough detail so that an adequate answer can be submitted.  I am you are only asking a single question, it's just that question cannot be answered, due to the lack of detail that wasn't provided.  *You indicated that any 64-bit application will crash, does that mean, 64-bit version of Internet Explorer crashes?*  How about if the behavior still exhibits itself while in Safe Mode?

Comment: I would: Download Procdump [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump]. Create a directory, e.g. C:\dumps\, then run the command (admin prompt): `procdump -ma -i c:\dumps`. Next time your application crashes you'll have a dump file. Maybe you can share this file?